# Making multiple tables and addind a 1:1..0 relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm pretty much a rookie so I would appreciate some comment on my code because I'm learning on my own here. I would like some feedback on my relationship mappings if I did them correctly because I'm in doubt at the moment. (Any tips on how to check this more properly myself is also welcome!)

I have a database with users but some of my users are Suppliers. Ofcourse this is an option. At first I just thought I'd assign a bool to it to store it in my database but now I'm extending it so that my suppliers can get reviews.

This is how I went about it.
My suppliers model:

```
    public partial class Suppliers
    {
    public Suppliers()
    {
        Id = GuidComb.GenerateComb();
    }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<SupplierReview> SupplierReviews { get; set; }
    public virtual MembershipUser user { get; set; }
    }
```

Then my review model:

```
public partial class SupplierReview : Entity
{
    //int: 0-255; score can only be 10 so this is a good fit.
    private int answerScore;
    private int timeScore;
    private int priceScore;
    private int qualityScore;

    public SupplierReview()
    {
        Id = GuidComb.GenerateComb();
        qualityScore = 5;
        timeScore = 5;
        priceScore = 5;
        answerScore = 5;
    }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    //these sets make sure that the score can only be one to 10
    public int QualityScore
    {
        get
        {
            return qualityScore;
        }
        set
        {
            qualityScore = value % 10;
        }
    }
    public int TimeScore
    {
        get
        {
            return timeScore;
        }
        set
        {
            timeScore = value % 10;
        }
    }
    public int PriceScore
    {
        get
        {
            return priceScore;
        }
        set
        {
            priceScore = value % 10;
        }
    }
    public int AnswerScore
    {
        get
        {
            return answerScore;
        }
        set
        {
            answerScore = value % 10;
        }
    }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public virtual MembershipUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual Suppliers Supplier { get; set; }
}
```

and then to the member model I added:

```
    public virtual IList<SupplierReview> SupplierReviews { get; set; }
    public virtual Suppliers IsSupplier { get; set; }
```

an then in my mappings:

```
public class SuppliersMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Suppliers>
{
    public SuppliersMapping()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.Id).IsRequired();

        HasMany(x => x.SupplierReviews).WithRequired(x => x.Supplier)
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("Suppliers_Id"))
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}

public class SupplierReviewMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<SupplierReview>
{
    public SupplierReviewMapping()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.Id).IsRequired();

        Property(x => x.Comment).IsOptional().HasMaxLength(1000);
        Property(x => x.QualityScore).IsOptional();
        Property(x => x.PriceScore).IsOptional();
        Property(x => x.TimeScore).IsOptional();
        Property(x => x.AnswerScore).IsOptional();

        HasRequired(x => x.User).WithMany(x => x.SupplierReviews)
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("MembershipUser_Id"))
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        HasRequired(t => t.Supplier).WithMany(t =>t.SupplierReviews)
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("Suppliers_Id"))
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    }
}
```

and in my membership mapping:

```
        HasOptional(x => x.IsSupplier)
            .WithOptionalDependent()
            .Map(p => p.MapKey("Suppliers_Id"));
        HasMany(x=>x.SupplierReviews).WithRequired(x => x.User)
            .Map(x=> x.MapKey("MembershipUser_Id"))
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Thanks for reading through this far. So where my doubts are is with the mapping in general and if I'm using WillCascadeOnDelete correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some mappings are opinion-based, it means that some times there is no "right answer". If I understand you scenario correctly, I recommend you to make these changes:

1. If a `User`can be a `Supplier`, but NOT ALL Suppliers are `User`:

   ```
   public class MembershipUser
   {
       public Guid MembershipUserId { get; set; }

       public IsSupplier { get; set; } //I like to have a discriminator field

       //if it is a supplier, there is a relationship with the supplier table
       //it it is not, the property will be null
       public Supplier Supplier { get; set; } 
   }

   public class Supplier
   {
        //pk 
        public Guid SupplierId { get; set; }             

        //navigation property
        public MembershipUser User { get; set; }

        //... other properties
   }
   ```

   mapping:

   ```
    modelBuilder.Entity<MembershipUser>()
        .HasKey(i => i.MembershipUserId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<MembershipUser>()
       .HasOptional(i => i.Supplier)
       .WithOptionalPrincipal(i => i.User)
       .Map(i => i.MapKey("MemberhsipUserId"))
       .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Supplier>()
       .HasKey(i => i.SupplierId);
   ```
2. If all Suppliers are `User`:

   ```
   public class Supplier
   {
       //The SupplierPK must be the MembershipUser Fk
       public Guid MembershipUserId { get; set; }             

       //navigation property, in case of the supplier is an user
       public MembershipUser User { get; set; }

       //... other properties
   }
   ```

   mapping:

   ```
   modelBuilder.Entity<MembershipUser>()
      .HasOptional(i => i.Supplier)
      .WithRequired(i => i.User)
      .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
   ```

About `SupplierReview`, it doesn't need the `MembershipUser` property, just the `Supplier` property:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierReview>()
  .HasRequired(i => i.Supplier)
  .WithMany(i => i.SupplierReviews)
  .HasForeignKey(i => i.SupplierId)
  .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey, first of thanks a lot for reviewing my code, I appreciate it a lot! 

The reason why I added MembershipUser to the SupplierReview was because the supplier gets a review from the standard user, so that I can collect data on the quality/deliverytime/price/responses of the suppliers that use my website. So the review is about the supplier, made by the users.